# Libjpeg write text at some specific position

Tags: c++, jpeg, libjpeg, libjpeg-turbo

Is there a way to output a text at some (x,y) position having a certain "size", such as a numeral '1'? For example in gnuplot, we can use

plot ... using x:y:size w labels center...

Is there something similar which I can use with the libjpeg library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No

libJPEG is only a loading/saving library. It allows the conversion of JPEG to other more workable formats and back. You will need some sort of image processing library (e.g. [OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#puttext)) or high-level graphics library (e.g. [DirectX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368038(v=vs.85).aspx), [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.2/classsf_1_1RenderTexture.php)). There are a lot of image libraries that implement writing of text on a bitmap. libJPEG will allow you to decode into a bitmap format in memory and from there you can work with pretty much any other library that has functions that write text onto a bitmap.

Personally, I would just use SFML since you can load a JPG file (or any image format for that matter), set that texture as a render target, render text, and then get the texture for that and save it back. But any high level graphics library should do the trick...like listed above.